# CMake: Detect Selected Linker

Tags: c++, cmake

Since `lld`, `ld`, `gold` and `mold` don't have identical feature I have found the need to determine the current linker at configuration time.

Is there a way, from within CMake to determine the current linker? For compiler, the variable `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID` can be used, I'm looking for something like a hypothetical `CMAKE_LINKER_ID`.

Comment: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18209

Answer (score 2):

As @KamilCuk observes in the comments, the current stance of the CMake developers is that this is not necessary. See the following issue: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18209

There, maintainer Brad King writes

> In practice I've found the need for this to be so rare that it is
> not worth providing an upstream abstraction.  Often the information
> needed it too specific and needs to be checked explicitly for the
> current linker via `try_compile` or something.

In the time since writing that comment, CMake 3.18 introduced the `CheckLinkerFlag` module, which will likely suit your needs.

An example:

```
include(CheckLinkerFlag)

check_linker_flag(CXX "LINKER:-some-flag" LINKER_HAS_FLAG)
```

See the docs: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckLinkerFlag.html